# SQL query, two query (A+B) faster than only B?

Tags: sql, sqlite

First of all, sorry for this title, it is hard to explain my question in a concise way.

I am working on a web server, using an SQLite database, this database contains several tables, 4 of them being used in the queries I will describe.

I can unfortunately not paste the queries, but to give an idea:

Query A:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN ... ON ... table_2
LEFT JOIN ... ON ... table_3
LEFT JOIN ... ON ... table_4
WHERE ... cond1 AND cond2
```

Query B:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN ... ON ... table_2
LEFT JOIN ... ON ... table_3
LEFT JOIN ... ON ... table_4
WHERE ... cond1 AND cond2
ORDER BY ... # This is the only difference
```

The results are obviously different as the second one sorts it while the first one does not.

When I run Query A, I get an average (cache cleared) of 6s, for Query B, I get an average (cache cleared) of 20s.

Fine, I understand that the ORDER BY take a lot of time.

Now, I did an experiment and found out that by running Query A (6s, cache cleared) then Query B (cache not cleared after performing Query A). I was expecting it to be around 14s, but got the result in (average) 6.5s, meaning that Query A+B takes 12.5s while only query B takes 20s.

I was not able to find a reason for such a difference, does anyone have any insights?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *cache not cleared after performing Query A* That's probably the reason there. Lots of result rows still cached in memory instead of having to be read from disk.

Comment: Sure, I get that, but why would Query A + (keep cache) Query B take less time than directly performing Query B?

Comment: Because, with the cache, query B speeds up. Why do you think Query A + (keep cache) Query B should not take less time than directly performing Query B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing your full schema, and especially all your indexes. Possibilities:

- SQLite query optimizer issue (something about the ORDER BY is causing it to chose a bad plan). Try using EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN: https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html
- It could be that the caching done while running Query A acts like a super "hint" to the optimizer, allowing Query B to be much faster. The optimizer is not smart enough to know what to cache to speed up Query B if it's only running it from scratch.

Edit: I missed this is for SQLLite, not MS SQL, but maybe this will help lead you to an answer

This sounds like it could be related to the query optimizer.
https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-the-basics/

The optimizer comes up with an execution plan for the query, and then caches it.
https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-sql-server-query-plan-cache/

```
SELECT ...
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN ... ON ... table_2
LEFT JOIN ... ON ... table_3
LEFT JOIN ... ON ... table_4
WHERE ... cond1 AND cond2 
AND 1=1
ORDER BY ... # This is the only difference
```

It could take some messing around to get an additional where clause that triggers a new execution plan, but you see the idea, the AND 1=1 is just a nudge to the query optimizer to get a new plan.

There's also the heavier handed option of clearing the cache
https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-sql-server-dbcc-freeproccache-command/